# Record DVI Signal (SXGA)

Tags: recording

I am trying to record a DVI Signal (SXGA) on a Mac (10.6.8). Do I need a scan converter for this ? If so, which hardware would be the best/easiest to use. Since it is 5:4, I also try to understand, if a scan converter is needed, to what resolution I can convert to, without loosing any information of the raw signal.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe more about your situation?  There are a few possibilities here, including direct capture, frame grabbers and scan converters.

Comment: I have a computer that generates a DVI signal with the resolution 1280x1024 and I need to be able to record it on a Mac. Unfortunately this computer can only generate the 1280x1024 signal and I already own a digitizer (AJA IO HD), but that won't record signals that are non standard (e.g. 1080p, 720p etc). Therefore I could get yet another product (scan converter) or maybe there is some less complicated/easier way.

Comment: Is it DVI-D or DVI-A?  Is direct screen capture a possibility or does it have to be done off the output?  (There is software that can record the screen buffer directly on many systems, depending on what's available on the system.)

Comment: DVI-I and No direct capture unfortunately is not possible. That was my first thought as well. I am thinking about some HDMI interface that e.g. Gamers use to record their screens. I would also need ext. Audio in. So if you know of a solution that can do both (Video&Audio), that would be ideal. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a better DVI scaler.  A good scaler should resize your video in-line to a supported resolution for your AJA IO HD.  One example I found of the kind of thing you are looking for is [here](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-DVI-UP-Down-Scaler-Converter.html).  I have no direct experience with that particular scaler, so double check that it will handle your exact needs, but the correct type of scaler will handle resizing your video feed to something that the AJA IO should be able to handle.

Also keep in mind if you are using DVI-A (analog) or DVI-D (digital) as it will impact both cost and quality of the scalers that are available as well as the type of input you use on the AJA IO.  I'd lean towards trying to keep a digital workflow, if you can, as it should preserve the highest overall quality.

As far as alternate capture devices, two of the main ones I normally consider (though I have no direct experience with the current generation) are the Black Magic Intensity and the Matrox MXO2.  I used to use Matrox capture stuff back in the day with great success, but have not used their newest stuff.